The spectrum of an element in a subalgebra is equal to its spectrum in the algebra
Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with an identity element, and let $B$ be a maximal commutative subalgebra of $A$. Prove that:$Spec_A(b)=Spec_B(b),\forall b\in B$.
It is easy to show that $1in B$ and $Spec_A(b) \subseteq Spec_B(b)$, but how does one deal with $Spec_B(b) \subseteq Spec_A(b)$?

Let $e$ be the identity element.
Note that if $b$ commutes with a member $c$ of $A$,
and $\lambda \notin Spec_A(b)$, i.e. $\lambda e - b$ has an
inverse in $A$, then that inverse also commutes with $c$:
$$ \eqalign{(\lambda e- b)^{-1} c &= (\lambda e- b)^{-1} c (\lambda e- b) (\lambda e- b)^{-1} \cr &= (\lambda e-b)^{-1} (\lambda e- b) c (\lambda e - b)^{-1}\cr & = c (\lambda e- b)^{-1}}$$
If $B$ didn't contain $(\lambda e- b)^{-1}$, you could replace $B$ by the algebra generated by $B$ and $(\lambda e- b)^{-1}$ and get a larger commutative subalgebra, contradicting the assumption that $B$ is maximal.  So $(\lambda e - b)^{-1}$ must be in $B$, which means that $\lambda \notin Spec_B(b)$.
